# Past participles and adjectives

Tags: participio

In most cases, we can just use the past participle if we need the adjective form of a verb, such as saying *camino olvidado* or *coche abollado*. When/why do we use *lleno* instead of *llenado*?

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe it's similar to the situation with *imprimir* and *impreso*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We say *lleno* rather than *llenado* because *lleno* is the original word from which the verb *llenar* derives, of which *llenado* is the passive participle. This comes all the way from Proto-Indo-European:

> PIE **pl̥h₁nós* (“full”) → Latin *plēnus* → Sp. *lleno*

So *lleno* exists as a simple word before the verb *llenar*, which is formed by derivation in the same way as other verbs, such as *vaciar* from *vacío*.

In contrast, the verb *abollar* exists before its participle *abollado* (there's no pre-existing simpler adjective **abollo*), and *olvidar* exists before *olvidado*. (There's *olvido*, but it's a noun and appears to be a back-formation from the verb.)

Of course there's also some randomness involved in which words stay or leave, and which are used for which purpose. Spanish could very well have regularized this situation, dropping *lleno* and using *llenado* as an adjective, following what is done with most other verbs. It sounds uneconomical, but then today most people say *búsqueda* instead of *busca* for "search (n.)"; a derived longer word has replaced a shorter, more primitive one.

Answer (score 2):

*I am new in this site but I will try my best.*

If we take a look to the grammar, *llenado* is different from the other two words. While *abollado* and *olvidado* are the participle of the verb and we can use it as an adjective, the word llenado it is not an adjective but a noun. Then, as all the nouns, they can be the subject of the sentence. If we want to use an article to say that is full, we have the word *lleno*.

So then:

The petrol tank is full  // El depósito de gasolina esta *lleno*.

The filling of the petrol tank cost 40€  // El *llenado* del depósito de gasolina costó 40€

Comment: Now that *llenado* is perfectly acceptable as an adjective, even if in most cases will be *lleno*

Comment: Also, *lleno* can be a noun (though only in very specific phrases such as *un lleno total* = "a full house [e.g. at the theater]").